# If I have 10 firefeeds in one app do I need do I need 10 firebases?

Tags: firebase

If I have 10 firefeeds in one app (one on each page) do I need do I need 10 firebases or can they be nested under one? Is it possible to set up 1000+ firefeeds under 1 firebase account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand your question.  Our [firefeed demo app](http://firefeed.io/about.html) allows an unlimited number of users to sign up and they each get their own feed.  E.g., [here's mine](http://www.firefeed.io/?profile=29201436). All of the data for it lives in a single Firebase.

If you're talking about having complete separate instances of firefeed under one Firebase (each with a distinct set of users and posts, etc.), you could do that too.  Since [Firebase's Data Structure](https://www.firebase.com/docs/data-structure.html) allows nested children, you could nest each instance under it's own location in Firebase.  E.g. /firefeed/1, /firefeed/2, etc.  You would need to update the security rules to be aware of this extra level of nesting, but it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Thanks Michael for you quick reply.